# Outer product of two rectangular matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

If I have a vector r , I can easily calculate its inner product

```
r=[1 2 3];
inner = r*r'
inner = 14
```

Same goes for the outer product

```
outer=r'*r

outer =

 1     2     3
 2     4     6
 3     6     9
```

Outer, as it should be, has NxN components (where N is the total number of components, here 3). Inner, on the other hand has m x m components (where m is the number of rows, here 1).
I want to be able to do this standard operation to rectangular matrices too. The inner product of rectangular matrices is easy enough:

```
 r =

 1     2     3
 1     1     1
 
inner=r*r'

inner =

  14    6
  6     3
```

Inner has  components (2x2=4) and this is what I expect from the matrix multiplication of r with its transpose.
Clearly, though, it is not clear how I should calculate the outer product of  with itself, because now the definition of "inner product with transpose"  and "outer product with itself"  have the same syntax in MATLAB. Indeed, if I try to repeat what I have done for the vector r, I obtain:

```
outer=r'*r

outer =

 2     3     4
 3     5     7
 4     7    10
```

Which is not the outer product of r with itself, as it's evident from the fact that it does not have NxN=36, but only nxn=9 components (where n is the number of column). What MATLAB has interpreted my calculation to be is the inner product of r transpose and r.
How do I obtain the proper outer product, whose components are all the combinations of products between components of r?

Answer (score 4):

The `*` operator in MATLAB calculates the [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

I guess what you want is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). It can be done with the [`kron`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a 6x6 matrix, you likely want to do

```
r(:) * r(:).'
```

`r(:)` is a vector with all the elements of matrix `r`.

If you are looking for the tensor outer product of `r` with itself, which will have a size of 2x3x2x3, then you need to do as follows:

```
r .* shiftdim(r,-2)
```

(with the 2 being the number of dimensions in `r`, and the `.*` the element-wise multiplication with implicit singleton expansion.)

Note that both answers produce the same set of values, as does the `kron(r,r)` [solution by yar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766511/7328782), but all three put the resulting elements in a different order.